# Can light wrap onto itself and become stationary?

Tags: visible-light, matter

This is possibly pure nonsense.

I read somewhere particles interact with themselves and this makes calculation complicated. No idea where I read it but I remember reading it.

I wonder if light can be seen as a string (not a reference to string theory, which I don't know anything about) normally open-ended, moving at C speed like a super fast caterpillar but when it gets closed it becomes stationary, like a particle of matter.

Like a dog chasing its tail or a snake eating its tail. The ensemble has internal speed but no external displacement.

Not sure how the front part of light would get attached to the rear though. Maybe its EM field or gravity. Also, maybe this would be possible only beyond a certain amount of energy.

Presumably, light wrapping onto itself would look like matter and not light.

This is just an admittedly vague question to see if something interesting can be said about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GR-phenomenon called a Photon Sphere (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere), but I would rather call it a photon circle. In this scenario, an object (like a black hole, for example) has a gravitational field so strong that light can go around it in a circular orbit. More precisely, one individual photon (which is like a particle) only has one position at any time - it just travels around the circle at the speed of light. The photon is never stationary - it always travels at the speed of light - but it does trace its steps every time it makes another revolution.

The trajectory of the particle is the set of all the photon's positions - so the trajectory of the particle is always the same (it's always the circle), but the photon is never stationary, nor does it ever collide with itself.

Comment: Not what I expected but this is interesting nonetheless! Thank you.